# SELECT temporary table and SET NULL for duplicate value

Tags: mysql

I have this temporary table that has duplicate value in `sale_val` column. Notice the duplicate `8764173.12` with `sale_id` of `120`. Is there anyway I can set one of the duplicate value in `sale_val` as `NULL` or `0.00`?

My temporary table:

[image]

For example I want the result to be like this:

```
sale_id | buy_val | sale_val   |
120     |   11.00 | 8764173.12 |
120     |   55.00 |  0.00      |
```

My temporary table query:

```
SELECT
  sale_id,
  buy_val,
  sale_val
FROM
  table1
```

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't add image link to your question. Add the error or code snippet instead.

Comment: I'm noticing that you've got duplicate `sale_id` as well. Probably you'd want to use grouping when creating the temporary table.

Comment: I added the snippet. Don't mind the duplicate `sale_id` value, what important was `sale_val` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create the temporary table using `GROUP BY`.
Here, I'm using `MIN` as aggregate function to get the buy and sale val, but you should use the [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) that express the logic that you want to apply.
Take a look at `GROUP_CONCAT` function too:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_t AS
SELECT sale_id, min(buy_val) AS buy_val ,min(sal_val) AS sal_val
FROM   table1
GROUP BY sale_id
```